# Creating adjacency List Graph

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, graph

I am trying to create adjacency list for graph by creating array of arraylist of type edge(include source,dest,weight) as in code below  :

```
public class Main {
    
static class Edge{
    
    int s;
    int d;
    int wt;
    
    Edge(int src,int des,int weight)
    {
        this.s = src;
        this.d = des;
        this.wt = weight;
        
    }
}
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //creating array of arraylist of type edge

        ArrayList<Edge>[] graph = new ArrayList[7];
        
        //Doubt regarding this line ,as why is it essential?
        graph[0] = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        
        //creating edge object 
        Edge e = new Edge(0,1,10);

      //adding it into arraylist
        graph[0].add(e);
        
        
        
    }
```

Since I have created array of arraylist of type edge , I think I can directly add into arraylist like graph[0].add(e) without writing
**graph[0] = new ArrayList();**

but it isn't working without it. Why I need to give above statement when my array is of arraylist so can't I add the elements directly?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9043523/5133585) answer your question?

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you so much . Yes it answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code declares `graph` to be an array of 7 `ArrayList`, with its elements initially (as in all arrays) set to their default values - `null` for objects, `0` for integers, `false` for booleans:

```
    ArrayList<Edge>[] graph = new ArrayList[7];
```

You can test it by adding this line below, or by stepping through with a debugger:

```
    System.err.println(graph[0]); // prints "null"
```

Your `new ArrayList[7]` only reserved space for an array of (`ArrayList`) objects, but did not reserve space for the 7 new `ArrayLists` you want to add. This allows you, for instance, to add subclasses of `ArrayList` to your array, or leave some slots with a `null` value, or add the same `ArrayList` to several slots. All of these options can be useful in some cases, so the compiler and language do not create empty new elements unless you explicitly them to do so. I would recommend using a loop:

```
    ArrayList<Edge>[] graph = new ArrayList<>[7];
    for (int i=0; i<graph.length; i++) {
        graph[i] = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    }
```